# In a Hilbert space $H$, $\exists! b \in F \subseteq H$ such that $d(a,b) = d(a,F)$

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm trying to do the following exercise:

Let $H$ a Hilbert space (Vector space complete with inner product), $F \subseteq H$ a closed convex set and $a \in H$. Show that $\exists! b \in F \subseteq H$ such that $d(a,b) = d(a,F)$

My teacher gave a hint that I can't see where it'll lead. He said this:

If $x_n \in F$ is a sequence such that $||a-x_n|| \to d(a,F)$, then
use the parallelogram identity to show $(x_n)$ is Cauchy.
I know that in vector spaces with inner product the parallelogram identity is true: $||x+y||^{2} + ||x-y||^{2} = 2||x||^{2} + 2||y||^{2}$. But I don't see how should I use it to prove $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. Since the space is complete it will converge, but why would this help me to prove existence or uniqueness of $b$?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The trick is that $(x_n+x_m)/2\in F$ as well (since $F$ is convex). Use this on
$$ 2\|a-x_n\|^2 + 2\|a-x_m\|^2 = \|2a -(x_n+x_m)\|^2 + \|x_n-x_m\|^2$$

Comment: $ 2\|a-x_n\|^2 + 2\|a-x_m\|^2 = \|2a -(x_n+x_m)\|^2 + \|x_n-x_m\|^2 \Rightarrow  \frac{\|a-x_n\|^2}{2} + \frac{\|a-x_m\|^2}{2} = \|a -\frac{(x_n+x_m)}{2}\|^2 + \frac{\|x_n-x_m\|^2}{4} $. Taking the limit (Since square is continuous): $ \frac{d(a,F)^{2}}{2} + \frac{d(a,F)^{2}}{2} = d(a,F)^{2} + \lim \frac{ \| x_n - x_m \| ^{2}}{4} \Rightarrow 0 = \lim \|x_n - x_m \|$, then it is Cauchy, Then $(x_n)$ converges to some element of $F$. But I still can't see why this will imply existence and uniqueness of $b$.

Comment: Is this right? $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, then $x_n \to b \in F$, then $\| a - x_n \| \to \| a - b \| = d(a,b)$. But $ \| a - x_n \| \to d(a,F)$, then by uniqueness of limit (Metric space is Hausdorff), $d(a,b) = d(a,F)$

Comment: If any minimizing sequence is Cauchy then the limit must be unique. Suppose $b$ and $b'$ are two possible limits. Then construct a sequence $x_n$ so that $x_{2n} \rightarrow b$ and $x_{2n+1}\rightarrow b'$. Now use Cauchy to conclude that $b=b'$.

Comment: What I did on my second comment was wrong?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer: That was ok and shows that you attain the minimum (but didn't show uniqueness of $b$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For the Cauchyness, put $x= a - x_n$, $y= a-x_m$ (as in your notation) for some positive integers $m>n$ and then use convexity! Limit of this sequence is a candidate for your $b$.